# Parser not recognizing a dash

Tags: vb.net, unicode

My program makes calculations on physics vectors and it allows copy/pasting from websites and then tries to parse them into the x, y, and z components automatically.  I've come across one website (http://mathinsight.org/cross_product_examples) that has (3,−3,1).  While that looks normal, that minus is actually not recognized by VB.  Visually, it is longer than the normal minus (− and -), but return the same Unicode of 45.  This picture shows the Unicode for every character (I added a minus in front of the first 3 for comparison) in the Textbox.  Also, from this website, I had to use Ctrl+c because right clicking shows that this is not simple HTML.

[image: Unicodes for the characters in the vector string]

One is valid (the first), but the second gives VB fits as shown below.  Either it won't compile (shown by the blue line below) or a simple assignment (the second one) wrecks havok on my form.

[image: Screen capture of VB not allowing the longer dash]

I have tried using

```
    vectorString.Replace("–", "-")
```

and pasting in the longer dash for the target string and a normal keystroke dash as the replacement, but nothing happens.  I'm guessing that since they both have the same Unicode.

Is there some way to convert the longer, invalid dash into the one recognized by VB?  I tried using dash symbol that Word likes to replace the minus sign with and it comes up as Unicode 150.  So, apparently there are at least three different kinds of dashes.  Any thoughts?

Comment: That “dash” is actually the *real* Minus Sign (U+2212). I don’t know how you are getting a character code of 45 but that’s clearly wrong, as the actual character code is &H2212. Incidentally, “have a Unicode” doesn’t make sense. Unicode is a standard for character encoding. What you can say is that a character has a Unicode character code.

Comment: I can't explain it either.  The keystroke dash is 45.  How is U+2212 the real minus sign?  Because it is bigger?

Comment: It’s the “real” minus sign because that’s how it’s specified. The “normal” minus sign is actually just a hyphen dash (used to concatenate words). It looks different from a minus sign. In particular, it’s usually shorter, and its vertical position is different: the minus sign has the same vertical position as the middle line of the plus sign (and the same length), whereas the hyphen doesn’t, in most fonts: “-+”. As for fixing your problem, `Replace` works. You just have to assign the result to something.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I guess the confusion is that his code is showing both chars as ASCII 45 (as shown in the image above), which begs the question of how he is converting them.

Comment: I just used Asc() after using Mid() on each character. It was actually luck that it worked out since that is the same function I used when learning on a TRS-80.  Ah, the memories.......  That also makes me wonder something ASCII was a long time before Unicode, so it appears to be legacy.  Is there an actual function to return Unicode or will ASC do that without a problem for characters outside the 255 range of ASCII?

Comment: You should use [`AscW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2bays67%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of [`Asc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9kb82hd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). `Asc` is for single-byte or double-byte character sets (SBCS or DBCS, e.g. ASCII, Shift JIS, or ISO 2022), while `AscW` returns the Unicode code point of the character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character from Math Insight is U+2212, minus sign. The character you tried using in your `Replace` call is U+2013, en dash. That's why your replace didn't work.

Beyond the standard ASCII hyphen (-, U+0045), there are two common dashes: the en dash (–, U+2013) and the em dash (—, U+2014). There is also a figure dash (‒, U+2012), but it is not as common.

Comment: Yep, that did it.  It would have taken a while to figure that out on my own.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying to use  vectorString = vectorString.Replace(Chr(2212), "-") and it causes VB to exit the function.  Execution ends right there just as if Return were used.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @TomK According to [`Chr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chr%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)'s documentation, it throws an exception if the provided character code is greater than 255. Instead, use [`ChrW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chrw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Also, the U+xxxx code points are hexadecimal, so you need to use hex notation `ChrW(&H2212)` or convert it to decimal `ChrW(8722)`.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks.  I had a typo by missing the &, but you covered all the bases just to be sure.  But, if an exception is thrown, why does the program continue?  It isn't in a Try/Catch.  This has happened a few times and it makes errors very difficult to track down.  Is there an option to turn on to give an exception and line number?